# Delete node with C# in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm Trying to Delete a node from XML with C#, but for some reason I can't.

What I doing wrong?

The code runs well, respond with true, but the XML don't change and the node is not eliminated.

This is my code to Delete:

```
internal static bool DeleteCamera(string name)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load("xmlpath.xml");
        XmlNode toDelete = xml.SelectSingleNode("//Camera[@Name='" + name + "']");
        if (toDelete == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            toDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(toDelete);
            xml.Save("xmlpath.xml");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is my XML result with WCF service:

```
<Cameras>
   <Camera Name="Camara1" Url="Camara1" Width="600" Height="800" />
   <Camera Name="Camara2" Url="Camara2" Width="600" Height="800" />
</Cameras>
```

Comment: Your code runs perfectly fine for me. Perhaps you are passing in the wrong string to the function? In the XML, the names are spelled **camara**, but everywhere else you use **camera**.

Comment: Yes, I also checked its perfectly fine. Just check the value of name you are passing.

Comment: If ithere is a problem with names, it should return false. I think, there are another things which are not shared with us.

Comment: That will not work for names like `'` (containing apostrophe)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you guys, the problem was the containing apostrophe (?) before and after name string.

```
XmlNode toDelete = xml.SelectSingleNode("//Camera[@Name='" +name+ "']");
```

But I don't know why I need to restart the service to see the changes if I have a Method to load the xml file.

Answer (score -1):

Use xml linq.  The name in xml is "Camara1" not "Camera1".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string removeName = "Camara1";
            XElement camera = doc.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "Camera") && ((string)x.Attribute("Name") == removeName)).FirstOrDefault();

            camera.Remove();

        }
    }
}
```